# Integrating density

Tags: integration, random-variables

Say $g(x)$ is the density of a continuous random variable, and $G(x)$ is its cdf. Im trying to understand some of the integral tricks I keep seeing everywhere.

I know that $\int g(x) dx = G(x)$. However, does it hold that 
$$\int x dG(x) = \int x g(x) dx$$

It kind of feels wrong because of the product rule of integration.

My current application: I need to solve

$$\int_0^b (x-a)dG(x)$$

I only know the Leibnitz rule when Im integrating over $dx$ and not $dG(x)$. So I was trying to decompose $dG(x)$ such that I integrate over $x$ - but I got stuck here.

Comment: Expected value is defined using Lebesgue integral not Riemann. Now the question becomes when does a Lebesgue integral can be calculated using Riemann calculus ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote is unclear, but
$$
\int_a^xg(s)ds = G(x)-G(a)
$$
since we dealing with pdf we require at the boundaries to be $0$ and $1$ respectively.
 and for simplicity and wlog we choose $a=0$, thus
$$
G(x) = \int_0^xg(s)ds 
$$
now
$$
\frac{dG}{dx} = g(x)\frac{\partial x}{\partial x} - g(0)\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(0) + \int^x_0 \frac{\partial }{\partial x}g(s)ds  = g(x)
$$
thus
$$
dG = g(x)dx
$$
this is true when $g(x)$ is a pdf.

you be glad to know that it holds for your application thus
$$
\int_0^b(x-a)dG = \int_0^b(x-a)g(x)dx
$$

Comment: Thanks for the general answer! Is there a similar rule for $\int x g'(x)dx$? I'd assume its $\int x dg(x)$ but that doesn't really help solving it.

Comment: The reason the above is valid goes in to probability theory beyond the scope of this question (I think anyway), but whilst $dG$ has meaning i.e a pdf $g(x)$, $g'(x)$ has little meaning (as far as I am aware). So you could knock up a rule, but then you are out of the realms of probability distributions. Though, just because I have yet to come across and application, doesn't mean there isnt one.

Answer (score 2):

$dG(x)$ is just $\frac{dG}{dx}(x)dx$, that's $g(x)dx$. So what you have mentioned is true.

Now:

$$\int_{0}^{b}(x - a)dG(x) = \int_{0}^{b}(x - a)g(x)dx = \int_{0}^{b}xg(x)dx - a\int_{0}^{b}g(x)dx = \int_{0}^{b}xg(x)dx - a(G(b) - G(0)) = etc.$$